# Is it possible to simulate the effect that place #ifdef inside another #ifdef #endif?

Tags: c++, syntax, macros

I was checking some import statement, and found some import statement is in the pattern like this:

```
#ifdef A

#ifdef B
//SOME SETTINGS 1 (some include,define,ifdef...)
#else
//SOME SETTINGS 2 (some include,define,ifdef...)
#endif

#else

#ifndef B
//SOME SETTINGS 1 (some include,define,ifdef...)
#else
//SOME SETTINGS 2 (some include,define,ifdef...)
#endif

#endif
```

which the macro of A is just inverse the macro of B,but "//SOME SETTINGS 1" and "//SOME SETTINGS 2" need to appear twice, so I try to rewrite that:

```
#ifdef A
#ifdef B
#else
#ifndef B
#endif

//SOME SETTINGS 1 (some include,define,ifdef...)

#else

//SOME SETTINGS 2 (some include,define,ifdef...)

#endif
```

but it failed to compile, is there any syntax to simulate this case that "//SOME SETTINGS 1" and "//SOME SETTINGS 2" only need to appear once?

Comment: I wonder why this question was downvoted. Struggling with the preprocessor can be frustrating.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is this:

```
#ifdef A
  #ifdef B
  #else
   #ifndef B
   #endif
           //SOME SETTINGS 1 (some include,define,ifdef...)
#else
          //SOME SETTINGS 2 (some include,define,ifdef...)

#endif
```

You have a mismathed number of #ifdefs, elses and endifs.

To do what you asked for:

```
#if (defined(A) && defined(B)) || (!defined(A) && !defined(B))
  // settings 1
#else
  // settings 2
#endif
```

This is how you generally approach these kind of problems. You set up a Karnaugh truth table:

```
A    B   => 1
A   !B   => 2
!A   B   => 2
!A  !B   => 1
```

Reading this table alound means you need to use settings 1 for when (A and B) are defined OR when (A is not defined and B is not defined)... hence in C:

```
(A && B) || (!A && !B)
```

Convert that to ifdef syntax and you're good to go.

Comment: What does the two lines `#ifndef B \n #endif`. This looks like an empty clause.

Comment: Edited answer to add Kernaugh truth table and how to actually solve all of these logical puzzles.

Comment: The condition can also be simplified to `defined(A) == defined(B)`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the `defined` operator (evaluates to `1` if the identifier is defined and `0` otherwise). You basically seem to want `SOME SETTING 1` if `A` and `B` are defined or both undefined and `SOME SETTINGS 2` otherwise:

```
#if defined(A) == defined(B)
//SOME SETTINGS 1 (some include,define,ifdef...)
#else
//SOME SETTINGS 2 (some include,define,ifdef...)
#endif
```

The direct comparision is because either you want `defined(A)` and `defined(B)` to be both one or both zero - and one and zero is the only alternatives for them.

Note that if you want to extend this to more than two alternatives you have to be careful to use `#elif` because `SOME SETTINGS 1` can alter subsequent tests if you repeat `#if`-`#endif` groups - that's why we need to use `#else` for the `SOME SETTINGS 2` part. For example:

```
#if COND1(A,B):
     // SOME SETTINGS 1
#elif COND2(A,B):
     // SOME SETTINGS 2
// etc
#else
     // DEFAULT SETTINGS
#endif
```

Comment: Agree. Smart. More concise.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the checks for definition like this.

```
#if (defined(A) && defined(B)) || (!defined(A) && !defined(B))
// SOME SETTINGS 1
#else
// SOME SETTINGS 2
#endif
```

Comment: This is different because if `SOME SETTINGS 1` defines or undefines `A` or `B` it would alter the meaning of the second condition. You could end up with both `SOME SETTINGS 1` and `SOME SETTINGS2`

Comment: ...and it is wrong, because it changed the logic from (A&&B) || (!A&&!B) to (A&&!B) || (!A&&B)...

Answer (score 0):

You want settings 1 when A & B are defined, or niether A or B are defined. This should do the trick:

```
#if (defined (A) && defined(B)) || (!defined (A) && !defined(B))
    //SOME SETTINGS 1 (some include,define,ifdef...)
#else
    //SOME SETTINGS 2 (some include,define,ifdef...)
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
#if (defined A && defined B) || (!defined A && !defined B)
//SOME SETTINGS 1 (some include,define,ifdef...)
#else
//SOME SETTINGS 2 (some include,define,ifdef...)
#endif
```